# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.'

Tags: php, parsing

I am new to php so apologies if this is a simple error.

I am trying to create a shopping basket for a website for a student project and get the error above. I got the code from a template posted online and modified some bits but cant solve this problem. The code I am using is below.

The line I am having issues with is the one starting echo "Logged in as " .

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['SESS_CHANGEID']) == TRUE) {
session_unset();
session_regenerate_id();
}
require("config.php");
?>

<?php echo $config_sitename; ?>
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="menu">
<a href="<?php echo $config_basedir; ?>">Home</a> -
<a href="<?php echo $config_basedir;?>showcart.php">View Basket/Checkout</a></div>
<div id="container">
<div id="bar">
<?php
require("bar.php");
echo "<hr />";
if(isset($_SESSION['SESS_LOGGEDIN']) == TRUE)
{
echo "Logged in as <strong>" . $_SESSION['SESS_USERNAME'] . "</strong>[<a    href="&quot; . $config_basedir. &quot;logout.php">logout</a>]";
}
else{
echo "<a href="&quot;. $config_basedir . &quot;login.php">Login</a>";
}
?></div>
<div id="main">
```

Thanks for any advice in advance

Comment: Its a typo error... 
echo "<a href="'. $config_basedir . 'login.php">Login</a>";

and 

echo "Logged in as <strong>" . $_SESSION['SESS_USERNAME'] . "</strong>[<a    href="'.. $config_basedir. .'logout.php">logout</a>]";

Comment: `"</strong>[<a href='". $config_basedir. "logout.php'>logout</a>]"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These will be better:

```
echo "Logged in as <strong>" . $_SESSION['SESS_USERNAME'] . "</strong>[<a href=\"". $config_basedir. "logout.php\">logout</a>]";

echo "<a href=\"". $config_basedir . "login.php\">Login</a>";
```

Just 'escape' quotation marks using `\` sign

Answer (score 1):

```
 instead of:  

    require ("bar.php");
    echo "<hr />";
    if (isset( $_SESSION ['SESS_LOGGEDIN'] ) == TRUE) {
        echo "<a href={$config_basedir}/logout.php>logout</a>"
    } else {
        echo "<a href={$config_basedir}/login.php>Login</a>";
    }
```